# Incrementing a variable in c# not working

Tags: c#, variables, increment

So I currently have the problem that I am unable to increment my variables. Using 'i++' in my code seems to do nothing and using any other form of incrementing a value does nothing too.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a number to see its times tables");
    int number = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
    int i;

    for (i = 10; i == 10; ++i)
    {
        int output;
        output = i * number;
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

All I am trying to do is create a basic loop but it is just stuck in an infinite loop, setting my variable 'i' to 10 causes the loop to work like its supposed to but it only executes once. The loop part becomes irrelevant.

Comment: very little, im using it to output times tables in order to relearn some of this as i havent done anything in months, ill figure out how to show it all in a second still working out how to use this site

Comment: Your setup has nothing to do with the issue. This is 100% logic issue with what you have written. For the record, the main difference between VS Community and VS Enterprise is really only extra features for debugging, and testing code, as well as some extra tools. The different editions does not compile code differently.

Comment: Google "comparison C#" and "assignment C#", and go read a couple of tutorials rather than just trying to hack it together. Your `for` statement is nonsensical based on your stated expectations.

Comment: Why was this question downvoted?  It has a clear problem statement and presents the code that illustrates the problem.  Maybe the OP could have researched a little more but I'm not sure that deserves a downvote.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
```

Your condition means that the loop executed an incorrect number of times.

By incorrect number looking at your post and various attempts this means anything from zero to 'a positive' (but incorrect) number of times.

An if statement is a compound statement. In your case your if statement is composed of three sub-statements - an initialization, a test and an increment.

When the if statement is executed these three statements are executed in order.

If the test returns false the loop is not entered so when the condition is 'i==10' and the initialization is 'i=1' the loop is not executed at all. When the initialization is 'i=10' then the loop executes once.

Sub-statements 2 and 3 are executed after each execution of the content of the loop and as long as statement 2 resolves to true the loop will continue being executed.

In our example using a condition 'i <= 10' would cause the code within the loop to be executed 11 times. 'i<10' would cause it to be run ten times. Care has to be taken when choosing sub-statement 2 (i.e. the loop condition). You have to make sure that the initial value in statement 1 and the increment in statement 3 (or alternatively a change to the value made within the body of the loop itself) guarantee that the condition will eventually fail.

If not then code has to be added to the loop to ensure that the loop will exit.

This will loop indefinitely

```
for (int x=0; x==0; ) {

}
```

This will NOT loop indefinitely

```
for (int x=0; x==0; ) {
     x++;
}
```

A test and break out of a loop could be done like shown in the following.

```
for (int x=0; x==0; ) {
  if (x==0) {
     break;
  }
}
```

If you do not ensure that the loop is guaranteed to terminate it could potentially never exit.

Comment: Wouldn't `i < 10` or `i <= 10` make more sense?

Comment: More specifically, in his condition the loop does not execute *at all*

Comment: @BradleyDotNET His prose differs from his code. I edited my answer after reading it in more detail. Look at the history. I will flesh it out.

Comment: @ccpgh must have been in the grace period then. I can't see the history

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I didn't know that a grace period existed. Good to know.

Comment: @ccpgh Yeah, edits by the OP within 5 minutes of posting (on any post, answers included) do not generate an item in the revision history *unless* somone else edits first.

Comment: @ccpgh Also, I would switch to <=, your code is fine with an increment of 1, but can result in an infinite loop with any other increment.

Answer (score 0):

By Using

```
(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

The range of i will be from 0 to 9

By using

```
(i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
```

The range of i will be from 0 to 10

By using

```
(i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
```

The range of i will be from 1 to 10